# How to capture return value of sproc?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a sproc, which I can't modify the signature of, that has a SELECT statement as its last line:

```
SELECT userid = @userid
```

where @userid is declared inside the sproc (not passed in).  Is there a way to capture the value of userid in a variable outside of the sproc?

If I want to capture two values by modifying the last line:

```
SELECT userid = @userid, somevar = @somevar
```

will that affect any existing code paths that are using this sproc (say calls being made in .NET)?  If not, how do I capture two values outside of the sproc?

These captures will all be done in SQL, not an application language.

Comment: I'm missing something here, what is your .net code doing with this. return from a proc, ExecuteScalar?

Comment: Please see [How to SELECT * INTO temp table FROM stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stored procedure that does a SELECT like that isn't actually sending back return values, it's sending back a result set. One way to capture that in your SQL would be to insert the results into a temp table.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTemp 
  (UserId INT, 
  SomeVar VARCHAR(50))

INSERT #MyTemp
  EXEC MySproc
```

At this point you can SELECT from #MyTemp into local variables.

Whether adding another column to the result will break any existing application code is really a big "it depends."